# How to remove target tr block using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to remove target tr block with text, when i run it i got perfect output but there is a problem i have seen that it **scraping** `<tr><td>Domain</td><td>Last Resolved Date</td></tr>` actually i don't want this line in my output so how can i remove it.Code bellow

## Got fix

#### Old Code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
url = "https://viewdns.info/reverseip/?host=github.com&t=1"
text = requests.get(url, headers=headers).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')

table = soup.find('table', attrs={'border':'1'})
domain = table.findAll('td', attrs={'align':None})

for line in domain:
    print(line.text)
```

#### Fixed

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
url = "https://viewdns.info/reverseip/?host=github.com&t=1"
text = requests.get(url, headers=headers).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')

table = soup.find('table', attrs={'border':'1'})
domain = table.findAll('td', attrs={'align':None})[2:]

for line in domain:
    print(line.text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the code.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
url = "https://viewdns.info/reverseip/?host=github.com&t=1"
text = requests.get(url, headers=headers).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')

table = soup.find('table', attrs={'border':'1'})
domain = table.findAll('td', attrs={'align':None})[2:]

for line in domain:
    print(line.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Filter out the first two objects in your `domain` variable:

```
domain = table.findAll('td', attrs={'align':None})[2:]
```